# render error message on a new line

Tags: java, xhtml, icefaces

I have this ice faces component with validator:

```
<ice:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{bean[field]}" required="#{required}"
    rendered="#{rendered}" styleClass="#{inputCssStyle}">
    <f:validator validatorId="#{validatorId}" />
</ice:inputText>
<br />
<ice:message style="color: red;" id="ageError" for="#{id}" />
```

As you see, I do want ice:message to be rendered **under** the input text so I put a < br /> tag.
The problem is that if there is no error the br tag will still be there and I do not want that...

Do you see how can I check if there is an error for this field (without using a property from the validator bean) directly in the xhtml page...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use css for that: `display: block;`, no need for the br tag.

`<ice:message style="color: red; display: block;" id="ageError" for="#{id}" />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ice:panelGroup>
<ice:inputText id="#{id}" value="#{bean[field]}" required="#{required}"
    rendered="#{rendered}" styleClass="#{inputCssStyle}">
    <f:validator validatorId="#{validatorId}" />
</ice:inputText>
<ice:panelGroup>
<ice:message style="color: red;" id="ageError" for="#{id}" />
```